# Pin verification for Gemalto .net smart card using c#

Tags: c#, .net, verification, smartcard, gemalto

I am trying to verify and change pin of gemalto .net card using c#. But when i tried to verify, using -

```
byte cla_verify = 0;
byte p2_pinReference = 0x80;
CardCommandAPDU quickVerify = new CardCommandAPDU(cla_verify, 0x20, 0x00, p2_pinReference, CardHex.ToByteArray("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF"));
CardResponseAPDU aRespAPDU = aCard.SendCommand(quickVerify);
```

it is returning -`SW 27033 (RSP 6999)`.

Any idea.
Whats wrong I am doing?

Comment: Status words are always specified in hexadecimals, so the 27033 value is not really needed.

Answer (score 1):

Status Word `69XX` means: Command not allowed.

I have looked at *NETSmartcardFramework.chm* provided inside the [NET Smartcard Framework SDK](http://www.gemalto.com/dwnld/5253_Gemalto.NET_SDK_v22.zip). There is no clue what CLA, INS, P1, dan P2, and Lc to be used. Instead, the PIN verification is already wrapped into PIN Class.

To verify a PIN value you can use

```
// PIN Class members
// PIN.Verify Method

public void Verify(byte[],int,int);
public void Verify(string);
```

But before that you need to initialize the PIN using constructor `PIN(byte[],int,int,int)` or `PIN(string,int)` and do checking if the PIN `isBlocked()` or `isVerified()`.

Some interesting articles and guides:

- [Building Your Own Security Application with the Gemalto .NET Smart Card V2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/263118/Building-Your-Own-Security-Application-with-the-Ge)
- [Gemalto .NET v2/v2+ Smart Card User Guide](http://www.swisstech.it/store/pdf/Gemalto.NET_User_Guide.pdf)

Comment: Well said, note that 6999 is not a status word that is defined by ISO 7816 as far as I know, so you are looking at a proprietary status word, specific to  .NET and/or Gemalto.

Comment: @owlstead: Correct. Only SW1='69' that is defined in ISO 7816-4

Answer (score 1):

Note, that while your PIN reference states a specific reference, the identifier zero from P2 means: "card shall know the addressed PIN". This may require additional previously sent commands like Manage Security ENvironment in the SET mode, or a certain security environment object or similar. Especially for the following Change Reference Data I would recommend to state the ID explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

PIN verification is explained [here](http://answersfactory.com/how-to-use-gemalto-idprime-net-510-smartcards/). You can try this code instead of yours. Looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

You want to verify PIN sending APDU, right. Lookup for document IDPrime .NET Smart Card - Integration Guide (APDU Encoding and Hivecodes). According to this document APDU for method verifyPIN (see Table 16 - Hivecodes for V5) should looks like this (example for role USER = 0x01 and PIN=1234) for:

```
80C200001BD800056F00C04B4E7FBD506B00044D53434D010000000431323334
```

Explanation:

APDU = APDU Header + APDU Payload

APDU Header is equal **80C20000 1B** where:

- 80C20000 - always the same
- 1B (hex) - 27 (decimal) is 1 byte payload
  length.

APDU Payload is equal **D8 0005 6F 00C04B4E 7FBD 506B 0004 4D53434D 01 00000004 31323334** where:

- D8 - nothing to change
- 0005 - Service Port Number (2 bytes)
- 6F - nothing to change
- 00C04B4E - Service Namespace Hivecode (4 bytes)
- 7FBD - Service Type Hivecode (2 bytes)
- 506B - Method Hivecode which is 506B for VeryfiyPin method (see doc)
- 0004 - Service Name length (0004)
- 4D53434D - UTF8 encoded Service Name (service name - MSCM (4D53434D))
- 01 - User role (USER = 0x01, ADMIN = 0x02, EVERYONE = 0x03)
- 00000004 - data size (PIN length in this case equals 4)
- 31323334 - hex value of PIN = 1234

If PIN is correct You should get 9000 in response.

Another example for PIN = 12345:

```
80C200001CD800056F00C04B4E7FBD506B00044D53434D01000000053132333435
```